# Error: Access not granted or expired. after deleting the bearer token from the PropertiesStore

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, google-oauth

I am using the [oauth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) for getting authentication with a service account and domain wide delegation to change the signature of a user:

```
function setSignature(email, signatureHtml) {  
var service = getDomWideDelegationService('Gmail: ', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic', email);

var resource = { signature: signatureHtml };

var requestBody                = {};
requestBody.headers            = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()};
requestBody.method             = "PUT";
requestBody.contentType        = "application/json";
requestBody.payload            = JSON.stringify(resource);
requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;

var emailForUrl = encodeURIComponent(email);
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/sendAs/' + emailForUrl;
var setSignatureResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);
}


function getDomWideDelegationService(serviceName, scope, email) {

  Logger.log('starting getDomainWideDelegationService for email: ' + email);

  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const key = props.getProperty("OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY");
  const serviceaccount = props.getProperty("OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL");

  return OAuth2.createService(serviceName + email)
  // Set the endpoint URL.
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

  .setPrivateKey(key)
  .setIssuer(serviceaccount)
  .setSubject(email)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setScope(scope);
 }
```

This worked fine until I replaced the `key` and the `serviceaccount` email from a hardcoded string to a value in the `PropertiesStore` as seen above. As I was doing that I accidently deleted the oauth2 entries in the PropertiesStore for every user. Now I get the following error

> Error: Access not granted or expired. at Service_.getAccessToken(Service:454:11)

After a while I somehow managed to get it working but only with one single user (which is the admin user). With all other users I still get this error.

Why is that? I thought the token is requested every time and it should not matter if I delete it from the PropertiesStore.

[EDIT]
Now also the admin account does not work anymore after I used the Userproperties and changed it back the way it was before...

**[EDIT2]**
I now can pin point the problem. Apparently reading the `key` from the PropertyStore is the problem. When I replace this line

`const key = props.getProperty("OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY");`
with the hardcoded value of the key it works.

I compared the value in the ScriptProperty with the correct one and they are identical. So what the heck?

Comment: why does that matter? In the example https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs the ScriptProperties are also used and frankly imho thats the place they should be

Comment: Try `getDomWideDelegationService('Gmail: ', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic', email).reset()`

Comment: so apparently the problem is that the keys are not equal but they should, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

After a long trial and error period I found out the problem. The key in the ScriptProperty was not 100% identical with the actual one.

I added the key in the Apps Script Project -> File -> Project Properties and created a new row and right clicked with the mouse and hit `Paste`.

When I now compared the hardcoded key with the one from the ScriptProperty like this:

```
var hcKey  = 'srbvwrvwrvwrvrwvrewv';
var propKey = PropertiesService.getScriptProperty().getProperty('mykey');
var val = propKey.localeCompare(hcKey); // val is 1.0
```

it looked like the that they are not the same.

When I instead stored the key via Apps Script before like this:

props.setProperty("mykey", 'srbvwrvwrvwrvrwvrewv');

it works. Please note that the value `'srbvwrvwrvwrvrwvrewv'` is not the actually key I just simplified it here.

So does that mean, by pasting it via context menu in the browser, some hidden character is added like the null character?

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem. In both cases I get matching keys, (When pasting it form the context menu and also when setting it via `setProperty`)

Comment: I was using Chrome if that helps

Comment: I also used Chrome